# minimize my nbconvert html output screen size

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I searched a lot for this issue but didn't come to any straight to the point answer, so I am turning to you here and hopefully someone can help direct me to the right path at least.

The issue is simple, I have normal jupyter Nb and I would like to share it with others by sending them html format file. Using the normal `!jupyter nbconvert --to html mynotebook.ipynb`will get the html export, but recently I started getting output with very wide screen (it uses the monitor screen).

How can I change the output screen size to maintain the same configurations even after exporting it to html?

In case my explanation wasn't clear I will add pictures:

- notebook before exporting: [image: here]
- After exporting:
  [image]

I don't want to create any special template, I just want to maintain the same parameters before exporting i.e. the width of the cells (inputs and outputs). Most of the answers I found here was talking about creating my own template or running some css code (both I don't have knowledge in...). Is there a ready to use template or argument that I can use to maintain the same layout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. I think the problem might be that `--to html` uses the Jupyter Lab template by default. Once I added `--template classic` to my call to `nbconvert` the resulting HTML-file was much smaller and resembled the actual Jupyter notebook much more closely.

Comment: This simple trick definitely solved it, Thanks Mink